# GO VSCode debugger not working on Apple with M1 Chip

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, apple-m1

I can run the go files, but I can't debug them in vscode.

Error:
"Failed to launch: could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into this as well after an upgrade to an Apple with an M1. There are several steps toward diagnosing the root cause of the issue. The first is to check the version of Go you've got installed.

```
> go version
go version go1.17.2 darwin/arm64
```

If the version is not `darwin/arm64` you've installed the wrong architecture for a Mac with an M1 chip. This is easy to do, since the default is `darwin/amd64`.

If this is the issue, uninstall your current version of go and install the arm64 equivalent located here: https://golang.org/dl/

Once the install is complete, it's time to verify two environment variables:

In a terminal:

```
> echo $GOOS 
darwin
```

```
> echo $GOARCH
arm64
```

If these are not set, go ahead and export them. I'd recommend adding them to your .zshrc or your equivalent.

```
export GOOS=darwin
export GOARCH=arm64
```

Finally, in VS Code, launch your project and enter the command bar in order to re-install all of the Go: Install/Update tools:

```
cmd + shift + p
Go: Install/Update Tools
```

This should allow you to run and debug successfully through VS Code.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.  The Install/Update tools was key.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the extension and that did not help.    The Install/Update tools made it work

Comment: I'm still having the same problem on go1.17.5 darwin/arm64, even though the variables are still set. Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 10):

In additional answer to someone who don't see "dlv" in Go: Install/Update Tools

There're 2 solutions

1. Remove "dlv" from go/bin -> reopen VSCode -> Run debugger -> Install "dlv" from VSCode the notification
2. Try to update it manually by using

   go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

Hope this help you guys :)

Comment: ty this worked. even after uninstalling GO and re-installing the arm64 version, this additoinal step was necessary.